# is it bad to forcefully reload a page?

Tags: javascript

Hello I am following a javascript course and the instructor when setting up a reset functionality for the app we are developing wrote a bunch of lines of code to reset all the variables to 0 or at their default value. I instead just used `location.reload();` as it is just a small web game. I was wondering is it bad to forcefully reload the page or it's the same as setting everything to default by code.

Comment: Reloading the page will not clear cookies, local storage or any other saved data. Additionally, you'll get through initialisation process again; if it's a costly process, it can slow down things.

Comment: In addition to what @ÁlvaroGonzález said - if the user was currently doing something (let's say they highlighted some text or similar) then that will also be lost. In ***extremely simple*** cases reload is fine. For anything that's not extremely simple - probably not.

Answer (score 2):

Reloading will not necessarily clear data set for a client, some cached data will persist and you'd have to clear them with some other way, there's also the risk of loading taking time.

It really depends on the context, in most cases its better to not reload just to reset values.